# How do i get the sum of three different row values in each column on WebTable using C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

How do i get the sum of three different row values in each column on WebTable using C#?

This is the code that I currently have:

```
IList<IWebElement> rows = _driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@id='data_3']/div/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[@class]")); 
for (int i = 1; i <= rows.Count; i++)
{
    IList<IWebElement> columns = _driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@id='data_3']/div/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[@class][" + i + "]/td[@class]"));

    for (int j = 1; j <= columns.Count; j++)
    {
        rows[3].Text.columns[j].Text + rows[3].Text.columns[j].Text
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried the above code so far and I can't seem to get it. I need help getting to the right direction

Comment: When you run your code, whats the error you are getting?

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML if you want help with locators. Also, a diagram or example of the table layout is going to be necessary to better understand what you are looking for and what the data looks like. You also need to add the current output and expected output.

Comment: One issue I see immediately is the line inside the for loop is concatenating two strings, not adding numbers. You are pulling `.Text` which is a string and adding it (concatenating) to another `.Text` string. Even the concatenated strings aren't being assigned to any variable. Not to mention this code won't even compile because you are missing a semicolon at the end of the line inside the for. You really need to create an [mcve] and post it.

Comment: Employment 1  1052 0 0 524 528
Employment 2  1050 0 0 526 524
Employment 3  1047 0 0 523 524
Employment 4  1033 0 0 509 524
Employment 5  5 0 0 1 4      3960
Employment 6  5 0 0 3 3      15     
I am having problem with this: row2 + row3 + row4 + row5 == row1. employment is the first column on the table

Comment: I have a simple WebTable and I am trying to apply a formula ( call values row2 + row3 + row4 + row5 == row1) in every column.

Comment: Anyone care to point me in the right direction? I want to compare the sum of row3, row6 & row8 to row1 in every column. I tried for(int I = 0; I<rows.count; I++} IList<IWebElement> columns=_driver.findElements(By.Xpath("//tr[@class]")); for(int j=0; j<columns.count; j++){rows[3].int.parse(columns[j].Text) + rows[6].int.parse(columns[j].Text) }